# Report on case team members - the number of cases worked on

Tags: reporting, case, case-teams

I need to create a report telling how many cases were handled by support personnel. Each case can be handled by one or more support engineers and all of them are added to this case's team. So, what I want is to get the list of engineers along with the number of cases in whose teams these engineers are included. For example:

```
Engineer         Cases #
Bill Smith       12
John Miller      25
Garry Mitchel    9
```

Is this possible?

Comment: If 3 users worked on same case - you'd expect same case to be counted 3 times? What have you tried so far? Looks like a summary or matrix report on Case Team Member object would be a good start... I don't think there's a standard report for that but you can easily create custom report type "Cases with or without Team Members" or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do this.
First of all, you need to create a new report type:
[image]

After this, create a new report with the matrix format based on this report type. Use the following fields and filters in this report:
[image]

That's all. However, this report does not allow filtering on a case team member role.

Comment: I'm new to reports can you help me like how differentiate january march like columns in reports

Comment: @Pavantej, point the mouse pointer over the Date/Time Opened column name and an arrow button will appear at the right side of this column header. Click this button and select a needed option from the Group Dates By menu.