# Cases report based on case team members' roles

Tags: reporting, case-teams

I have found a way to create a report telling how many cases were worked on by a person using the case team functionality ([see this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38564/report-on-case-team-members-the-number-of-cases-worked-on)). However, I cannot use a case team member's role in a filter. So, I can see report for all case team members, but not only for team members with specific role.

Does anyone know whether it is possible to filter case team members by their roles in reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that does not appear to be available out of the box yet, but there is an idea out there [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l61tAAA). Vote it up!